# What is the "oldest joke in the book?"

Tags: history, jokes

What is the earliest recorded joke in a published work in the English language?

Comment: Must it be a joke in english? In other words can it be a joke in latin in an otherwise english book?

Comment: Modern English? Middle English?  Old English?  Lots of English out there, AG.

Comment: "In the bigynnyng God made of nouyt heuene and erthe." — John Wycliffe, writing in the 14th century.

Comment: "What does Grendel eat for breakfast? Danish!" Or possibly Beowulf saying "Your mom!"

Comment: But the Grendel eating Danish joke would have not originally been in English.  Nice try, though!

Comment: Likely some combination of *eower* and *mōdor*. Seriously though, what English are we talking aboot?

Comment: The Miller's Tale was always a favourite of ours at school, at the age of about 15.  http://www.librarius.com/canttran/milltale/milltale698-707.htm

Comment: "Who introduced chiropody to the Saxons?" _"William the Corn-curer."

Comment: @Cyberherbalist the meta-joke I was attempting was that I gave a joke in Modern English about a story in Old English. It would seem it didn't work :(

Comment: I think this is inherently POB, since it depends more on how far back you're prepared to go and still call it "English" than anything else.

Comment: There was an Angle, a Pict and a Scot...

Comment: @JonHanna: Oh, it worked all right.  I even chuckled at it.

Comment: It may not have been meant or seen as a 'joke' until our times, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the oldest recorded joke in any form of English is about 1,000 years old, and is found in the Exeter Codex, written in Old English.

See the article in Wikipedia about the [Codex Exoniensis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exeter_Book).

The jokes in question are riddles in the form of double-entendres.

Answer (score -1):

[The oldest English joke is from 900AD](http://historum.com/art-cultural-history/35511-earliest-jokes-history.html)

The joke itself is not much about the English Language & its Usage.

I am yet to convince myself of its source, authenticity and vintage, though.

Comment: The one they mention as the oldest English joke there, is in the Exeter Codex, as given by Cyberherbalist in his answer. There's another in the same text that is basically a variant of the same, in that it leads you to suspect the answer to a riddle will be "penis" but it turns out to be something else.